# Clone a repo, just to get its content, in a subdirectory of another Git repo

Tags: git, laravel, github

Tired of making the same directories and creating the same files every time I'm starting a new Laravel project, for the front matters, I decided to make a Git repo with `assets` and `views` folders and some files inside, just to have my structure ready quickly.

[This repo can be accessed here](https://github.com/plebot/laravel-front-skeleton) (there is nothing useful regarding this question, this is just to be clear about what I want to do)

The idea is to pull/fetch/use-the-term-you-want that very repo inside my Laravel project (which will be, of course, a Git repo on itself), and that's all.

---

To be perfectly clear, the steps would be like this:

1. Start a new repo `my-new-project`
2. Deploy a fresh Laravel install (following official instructions)
3. Go into `resources` directory
4. **Pull the content from my front-skeleton repository**
5. Start working and forget about the front-skeleton repository which will now be related to the project, and won't need to be updated

---

I insist on the fact that I'm not talking about further operations to that Git repo, I'm really talking about **getting the content once and for all, then forgetting even the existence of that Git repo**.

- I heard about *subtrees* or *submodules* but that seem to be too much for my needs ;
- I didn't find a way to use *remote* correctly (my front-skeleton was pulled but at the root of my Laravel project, not in my `resources` sub-folder).

What would be the best way / best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That could be handled by a script that:

1. Issues `git clone --depth=1 <url> <destination>` on the repository, and then
2. Removes the `.git` folder inside the newly created `<destination>` directory

As a result, you get all the contents from your git repo, and that's all.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I got a `fatal: destination path 'resources' already exists and is not an empty directory` (because the `resources` directory already exists and have already some Laravel-related files)

Comment: Well, yes, it has to be an empty directory. You can not clone to a directory that is not empty. You could clone to a temporary directory and then copy the files over.

Comment: Hum, yep, probably, but I was looking for something more "2017"